# Java type inference from interface

Tags: java, type-inference

I have these two interfaces:

```
public interface FieldValue<T> {

  public String getLabel();
  public T getHrValue();
  public T getPicValue();
  public T getMinusOneValue();
  public T getMinusTwoValue();

}
```

and

```
public interface Field<T> {

  public List<FieldValue<T>> getValues();
  public void injectHrValue(ReportData data);
  public void injectPicValue(ReportData data);
  public void injectMinusOneValue(ReportData data);
  public void injectMinusTwoValue(ReportData data);
  public void debug();

}
```

I have then a class which contains a list of such Field type.
If I try to iterate in this way getValues() is not able to infer the FieldValue type but only Object.

```
        for (Field f : myclass.getFields()) {
            for(FieldValue fv : f.getValues()) { //error, cannot convert element type Object to FieldValue
            }
        }
```

Can someone explain me why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: What type is the `Field`'s generic type? You have specified `Field<T>` so I presume you need to specify the concrete type of `T` in your second code snippet?

Comment: Declare the loop variables as `Field<?> f` and `FieldValue<?> fv` (or with a specific type parameter, if one is available).

Comment: See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). You are using raw types `Field` and `FieldValue` in your last code snippet.

Comment: @AndyTurner Not when I was typing my comment ... :-)